# Como funciona o Lazy Load Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

É o seguinte pessoal, pelo que vi no *Entity* para utilizar o *Lazy Load* você deixa a propriedade sem a keyword **virtual**, e o eager com o virtual.

Porém, vi em alguns posts de blogs que o pessoal utiliza o 
*`Configuration.EnableLazyLoading = false/true;`* para ativar ou desativar o *Lazy Load*.

Fiquei em dúvida de como funciona essa questão no *Entity*, obrigado!

Comment: Favoritei. Respondo daqui a pouco.

Comment: Você inverteu a explicação do uso de `virtual`.

Answer (score 20):

No Entity Framework a carga preguiçosa (*Lazy Load*) é configurada por padrão. Suponha um Model de Produtos como o exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Produto 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProdutoId {get;set;}
    public Guid ProdutoCategoriaId {get;set;}
    public Guid FabricanteId {get;set}

    [Required]
    public String Nome {get;set;}

    public virtual ProdutoCategoria ProdutoCategoria {get;set;}
    public virtual Fabricante Fabricante {get;set;}
}
```

Neste caso, `ProdutoCategoria` e `Fabricante` não são carregados quando um `Produto` é carregado. Ao buscar os dados do `Produto`, o que é preenchido em `ProdutoCategoria` e `Fabricante` são classes do tipo `DynamicProxy`. Essas entidades só vão se tornar objetos dos respectivos *Models* quando forem acessados diretamente.

### E o que é, afinal, um *DynamicProxy*?

É um objeto que finge ser outro (ou, no caso, o objeto de um *Model*). Ao ser acessado, o Entity Framework efetivamente irá ao banco buscar os dados desse objeto e o *DynamicProxy* se transformará no objeto do *Model*.

Tecnicamente falando, o Entity Framework prepara 3 consultas para o exemplo:

- Uma para o `Produto` em si;
- Uma para `ProdutoCategoria`;
- Uma para `Fabricante`;

Inicialmente apenas a primeira é disparada. As outras só são disparadas se os objetos forem acessados.

### E o Eager Load?

A carga adiantada (*Eager Load*), no exemplo, carregaria todos os dados de uma vez. O Entity Framework, para este caso, faria apenas uma sentença com *joins* e logo após a transliteração dos resultados para seus respectivos objetos.

É fácil notar que desta forma, qualquer carga de cardinalidade N acarreta em problemas de desempenho. O *Eager Load* vale apenas para casos em que há muitas relações entre tabelas de 1 para 1.

Comment: "No Entity Framework a carga preguiçosa (Lazy Load) é configurada por padrão", isso quer dizer que vem setado true ou false?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Vem true.

Comment: Cara, então tem algo de errado com o meu, pois só vem false...

Comment: A propriedade System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.LazyLoadingEnabled vem definida para true por padrão. No entanto, sem o uso do modificador virtual (em Fabricante, no exemplo), o LazyLoadingEnabled true não faz efeito. Sem o virtual, uma alternativa seria usar o Load explícito em suas queries: context.Entry(produto).Reference(p => p.Fabricante).Load(). Mais em https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.