# Como passar um objeto ou lista de objetos do Controller para View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Pedido pedido)
        {

            List<Produto> lista = new List<Produto>();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Cliente cliente = unitOfWork.ClienteRepository.Busca(pedido.ClienteId);
                Produto produto = unitOfWork.ProdutoRepository.Busca(pedido.ProdutoId);
                lista.Add(produto);
                pedido.produtos = lista;
                pedido.cliente = cliente;
                unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Adiciona(pedido);
                unitOfWork.Salva();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(context.Produtos, "ID", "Nome", pedido.ProdutoId);
            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(context.Clientes, "ID", "NomeCliente", pedido.ClienteId);
            return View(pedido);

        }
```

Até ai OK...consigo salvar meu pedido com um cliente instanciado e uma lista de produtos...porém quando esse controller passa esse pedido para minha View INDEX...o objeto cliente e a lista de produtos chega vazia.

VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjetoZeus.Models.Pedido>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Lista de Pedidos</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar Novo", "Create")
</p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Pedidos</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)</th>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Preço</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cliente)</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.produtos[0].Nome)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.produtos[0].Preco)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.cliente.NomeCliente)
               </td>
           </tr>

        }
    </table>

</fieldset>
```

Action da Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Pedidos);
        }
```

classe UnitOfWork

```
public PedidoRepository PedidoRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (pedidoRepository == null)
                {
                    pedidoRepository = new PedidoRepository(context);
                }

                return pedidoRepository;
            }
        }
```

PedidoRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjetoZeus.Models
{
    public class PedidoRepository
    {
        private bool disposed = false;
        private Contexto context;

        public PedidoRepository(Contexto context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void Salva()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Adiciona(Pedido pedido)
        {
            context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
        }

        public Pedido Busca(int id)
        {
            return context.Pedidos.Find(id);
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            Pedido pedido = Busca(id);
            context.Pedidos.Remove(pedido);
        }

        public List<Pedido> Pedidos
        {
            get
            {
                return context.Pedidos.ToList();
            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o código da sua action "Index". Sua action "Index" tem que buscar os seus pedidos para serem visualizados na view.

Comment: postei...as unicas coisas que se perdem quando chega na view é o objeto Cliente e a Lista do tipo Produto

Comment: Cliente e Produtos estão carregados na sua consulta de pedidos ? Se estiver usando Entity, está com o lazy load ativado ?

Comment: Sim estão carregados e estou usando Entity...o que é lazy load ?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20646/como-funciona-o-lazy-load-entity-framework

Comment: Se chega vazia, o repositório não está fazendo o que deve. Como está o código do repositório?

Comment: Na action Create do Controller eu alterei pra : return View("Index",unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Pedidos); no lugar de          return RedirectToAction("Index"); e funcionou...mas nao entendi porque...os novos pedidos que eu adiciono ele traz certinho agora os antigos continuam nulo

Comment: olhando bem só o ultimo pedido que eu adiciono traz os dados certos

Comment: Tem alguma coisa muito errada no repositório, e essa solução de `return View()` é péssima. Você está usando o que para a camada de banco?

Comment: To usando aquele DbContext do Entity

Answer (score 5):

Esta é mais uma das perguntas que mostram o despropósito (e a inutilidade) de implementar repositório com Entity Framework (que já é um repositório). [Explico tudo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696), mas como você está começando, vou explicar etapa por etapa do porquê.

Este é seu código principal:

```
        List<Produto> lista = new List<Produto>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Cliente cliente = unitOfWork.ClienteRepository.Busca(pedido.ClienteId);
            Produto produto = unitOfWork.ProdutoRepository.Busca(pedido.ProdutoId);
            lista.Add(produto);
            pedido.produtos = lista;
            pedido.cliente = cliente;
            unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Adiciona(pedido);
            unitOfWork.Salva();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Em primeiro lugar, a maneira com que você formatou seu domínio só permite que um produto tenha um pedido. O correto seria definir uma entidade associativa entre produtos e pedidos, como, por exemplo:

```
public class ProdutoPedido
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoPedidoId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
}
```

Em segundo lugar, estes métodos são absolutamente inúteis:

```
    public void Salva()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Adiciona(Pedido pedido)
    {
        context.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
    }

    public Pedido Busca(int id)
    {
        return context.Pedidos.Find(id);
    }

    public List<Pedido> Pedidos
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Pedidos.ToList();
        }

    }
```

Você ocupa a pilha de chamadas pra realizar operações que o contexto já realiza. E agora vem o principal motivo de você jogar este repositório fora (além do contexto transacional que é impossível de acontecer com esta estrutura, mas isto é outro assunto). Aqui:

```
    public PedidoRepository(Contexto context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Não há garantia alguma que, ao selecionar produtos e clientes, você esteja usando o mesmo contexto, o que causa vários problemas ao persistir os dados.

Uma solução que funciona, portanto, seria algo assim:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Pedido pedido)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cliente = contexto.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClienteId = pedido.ClienteId);
            var produto = contexto.Produtos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProdutoId = pedido.ProdutoId);
            var lista = new List<ProdutoPedido> {
                new ProdutoPedido { Produto = produto }
            };

            pedido.produtoPedidos = lista;
            pedido.cliente = cliente;

            contexto.Pedidos.Add(pedido);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(context.Produtos, "ID", "Nome", pedido.ProdutoId);
        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(context.Clientes, "ID", "NomeCliente", pedido.ClienteId);
        return View(pedido);
    }
```

Comment: Eu achava mais simples usar a classe DbContext direto...mas me disseram que era melhor usar esses repository...vou alterar a estrutura do jeito que você mostra aqui...valeu Cigano !

Comment: Quem disse? O Eduardo Pires?

Comment: hahahaha na verdade foi um colega meu