# Debugar lazy loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Senhores,

gostaria de visualizar todas as consultas que são geradas quando uso lazy loading. 
Ao debugar visualizo apenas a principal.

No controller Treinamento esta assim:

```
public class TreinamentosController : Controller
{
    private DbContext db = new DbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        IList<Treinamento> treinamentos = b.Treinamentos.ToList<Treinamento>();
        //var treinamentos = db.Treinamentos.Include(t =>t.Departamentos);
        return View(treinamentos.ToList());
    }
```

Na view esta assim:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Departamentos.NomeDepartamento)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomeTreinamento)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Creditos)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departamentos.NomeDepartamento)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeTreinamento)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Creditos)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Editar", new { id = item.TreinamentoID}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Detalhes", new { id = item.TreinamentoID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Excluir", "Excluir", new { id = item.TreinamentoID }) 
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Ao debugar visualizo apenas a consulta referente ao Treinamento, não consigo visualizar a consulta referente ao departamento, como visualizo?

no debug:

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[TreinamentoID] AS [TreinamentoID], 
    [Extent1].[DepartamentoID] AS [DepartamentoID], 
    [Extent1].[NomeTreinamento] AS [NomeTreinamento], 
    [Extent1].[Creditos] AS [Creditos]
    FROM [dbo].[Treinamento] AS [Extent1]}
```

Comment: Torre, da próxima vez, dê uma formatada no seu código. =)

Comment: Rubico,ok. Foi mal.rs

Answer (score 1):

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20672/20615) explica muito bem o que é **Lazy Loading** e como ele funciona no **Entity Framework**, mas em resumo:

> Neste caso, `Departamento` não é carregado quando um Treinamento é carregado. Ao buscar os dados do Treinamento, o que é preenchido em Departamento são classes do tipo DynamicProxy. Essas entidades só vão se tornar objetos dos respectivos Models quando forem acessados diretamente.
> -[@CiganoMorrisonMendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20672/20615)

#### Então, quando que um `Departamento` é em fim carregado?

No momento em que você o chama, mas especificamente nesta parte:

```
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departamentos.NomeDepartamento)</td>
```

Neste momento o Entity Framework faz uma busca em seu banco de dados e trás o Departamento esperado. A consulta que ele faz é essa (apenas resumi os campos):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[DepartamentoId] AS [DepartamentoId], 
    [Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome]
    FROM [dbo].[Departamentoes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[DepartamentoId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 uniqueidentifier',@EntityKeyValue1='A96D7FCE-6FFE-4F97-B6DD-9A83DD8B0109'
```

Antes deste momento, ele apenas faz uma consulta de `Treinamentos` normal, dessa forma:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[TreinamentoId] AS [TreinamentoId], 
    [Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome], 
    [Extent1].[DepartamentoId] AS [DepartamentoId]
    FROM [dbo].[Treinamentoes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[TreinamentoId] = @p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='72A8B3DC-A998-47D8-BCF6-D8CDF21DBD29'
```

> As consultas foram geradas pelo **Entity Framework** na tela de Details básica gerada pelo Scaffolding do Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Randrade, entendi sua explicação. Muito boa. Porém, quando é que você consegue enxergar esta consulta do DEPARTAMENTO quando esta realizando o debug? Eu consigo enxergar apenas a do TREINAMENTO no controller, executando o debug passo a passo.

Comment: @Torres Essa consulta é vista no [SQL Server Profiller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181091.aspx) uma ferramenta da Microsoft.

Comment: Outra coisa, supondo que no TREINAMENTO terá os valores "C# basico", "C# Intermediário", "C# avançado", "Java Basico". E para o departamento tem "Dep A", "Dep B", "Dep C", "Dep D" cada um ligado a um treinamento específico. Após realizar a consulta em TREINAMENTO ele realizará a consulta em DEPARTAMENTO, quando este for carregado, então será realizado 4 consultas em DEPARTAMENTO para buscar seus valores?

Comment: @Torres Isso depende da forma que você está fazendo. Se está usando o **Lazy Loading**, para cada departamento diferente ele irá fazer uma busca. Porém, você pode utilizar o `Include(t => t.Departamento)` em sua consulta, que ele fará um `Inner Join` na tabela `Departamentos`, o que evita ir ao banco tantas vezes.

Comment: Valeu Randrade, obrigado.

Comment: Indica um livro bom de C# ou curso?