# Problema com herança

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, herança

Estou com um problema com uma pesquisa no banco, vou tentar explicar na melhor forma possível e mais clara.

Tenho uma tabela `Pessoa` e um tabela `Cliente`, a ultima herda de `Pessoa`, eu também tenho uma tabela `Unidade`  e uma `MensagemUnidade`.

A Tabela `MensagemUnidade` tem relação com cliente da seguinte forma :

```
public class MensagemUnidade
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public int UnidadeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual Unidade Unidade { get; set; }
}
```

Estou usando o modelo  DDD(Domain-Driven Design) na construção do projeto, quando eu tento fazer uma pesquisa em `mensagemServico`  ele traz a mensagem, traz a empresa, e ate o `ClienteId` , mas o objeto `Cliente` vem nulo.

Não sei o que eu possa ter feito de errado, na tabela Cliente possui apenas o `PessoaId` eu adicionei uma pessoa e então adicionei essa pessoa ao cliente, se eu pesquiso por aquela `PessoaId` ele retorna um `Cliente`, mas ele não  faz traz  quando busco mensagem.

A Minha Classe `Cliente` não possui nenhuma classe de ligação (Ex Unidade) porem minha classe unidade possui uma  `Coleção de Clientes`.

Caso alguém possa me ajudar ficarei extremamente grato, se faltar informações e só e avisar.

No me contexto esta contem a seguinte linha no metodo `onModelCreating`:

```
 Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

No exemplo que eu segui no `OnModelCreating` do `Contexto` é usando um codigo parecido com esse

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteLoja>().HasRequired(v => v.Loja).WithMany(m => m.Clientes).HasForeignKey(f => f.LojaId);
```

eu não coloquei nada parecido no meu codigo, é necessario? se sim porque?

EDIT: Essa é a pesquisa que eu faço  :

```
 List<MensagemUnidade> mensagens = this.mensagemServico.GetMany(l => l.UnidadeId == unidade.UnidadeAtual && l.OrigemId == (int)enumOrigemMensagem.USUARIO).OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio).Skip(mensagemModel.PaginaAtual * 20).Take(20).ToList();
```

EDIT 2 :
Este é o método que eu uso como getMany, existia um projeto anterior aqui  e eu preciso fazer um novo e estou usando este anterior de base, em uma pesquisa semelhante ele traz as informações necessarias mesmo sem o include ou algo do tipo, todo o resto esta igual ao meu codigo menos no contexto que eu nao tenho nada do tipo:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteLoja>().HasRequired(v => v.Loja).WithMany(m => m.Clientes).HasForeignKey(f => f.LojaId);
```

esse e meu metodo getMany:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where);
    }
```

Comment: `GetMany()`? Você tem como postar a implementação deste método?

Comment: @WilliamCézar, conselho, abra mão do EF ou do DDD, eu particularmente ficaria com o EF ;D

Comment: @TobyMosque Eu diria que eles nao sao mutuamente exclusivos, apenas  tem que fazer as coisas de forma que sejam minimamente organizadas.

Comment: Estou procurando conteudo para tentar entender o funcionamento, mas esta bem complicado, o resto esta tudo funcionando como deveria, acho que vou deixar uma chamda personalizada no servico em que tenha include e que adicione o cliente, como eu tenho 2 camadas que precisam acessar o banco , APi e Web ,eu uso o DDD , para poder ter uma semparação das camadas.

Comment: @BrunoCosta é possível, mas o overhead vai tomar horas de desenvolvimento, o seu código não vai ser mais fácil de ser mantido, você vai criar limitações artificiais ao EF e dificilmente você terá ganho de legibilidade. Então se não há ganho de Manutenabilidade, Legibilidade, Desempenho ou Tempo, pq fazer uso de uma abordagem desta?

Comment: Mais uma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696

Comment: @BrunoCosta São quase. Pode ser considerado um anti-padrão. [Explico aqui](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/10/14/entity-framework-e-o-fim-da-era-dos-repositorios/).

Comment: @TobyMosque Tudo depende daquilo que entende por `ddd` se calhar eu entendo `ddd` duma forma diferente da sua. Demora horas de desenvolvimente depende apenas da abstracao que voce está a criar. ^ eu ja vi essa  resposta e concordo com ela. Se quiser venham a um chat e temos uma conversa xP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o `LazyLoad` voce pode aceder á propriedade `Cliente` contúdo necessita que o `contexto` ainda esteja vivo.

Se quiser aceder á propriedade `Cliente` depois disso terá que carregar de forma `Eager`. No seu caso este é mesma a solucao ideal para evitar o problema do [`N + 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

Conforme o @Guilherme de Jesus Santos indicou voce pode usar o `Include`. Para usar a versao `lambda` voce precisa ainda de incluir o namespace `System.Data.Entity`

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

<s>O resultado final seria:</s>

```
this.mensagemServico.Include(c => c.Cliente)
    .Where(l => l.UnidadeId == unidade.UnidadeAtual && l.OrigemId == (int)enumOrigemMensagem.USUARIO)
    .OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio)
    .Skip(mensagemModel.PaginaAtual * 20).Take(20).ToList();
```

A solucao que voce tem é alterar a sua classe `mensagemServico`. Na verdade o seu método `GetMany` pode nem fazer muito sentido. Eu sugeria voce implementar um método por cada query/processo. Se isso implica muitas alteracoes no seu código neste momento deixe o `GetMany` onde ele está.

Por exemplo para este caso voce criaria o seguinte método:

```
public IEnumerable<MensagemUnidade> GetMensagensDoUsuario(int unidade, int pagina)
{
     return dbset.Include(c => c.Cliente)
        .Where(l => l.UnidadeId == unidade && l.OrigemId == (int)enumOrigemMensagem.USUARIO)
        .OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio)
        .Skip(pagina * 20).Take(20).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Mesmo adicionando a System.Data.entity o .include() não esta sendo reconhecido.

Comment: @WilliamCézar estou a ver que `mensagemServico` nao é um `DbSet `. Faca isso sobre o `DbSet` do contexto. Exemplo: `contexto.MensagemUnidade.Include`

Comment: @WilliamCézar você está usando o "padrão" DDD. Logo, **`mensagemServico`** é um meio termo para acessar o `DbSet`, por isso não existe `include`.

Comment: @WilliamCézar Este um das dezenas de problemas de usar o padrão DDD. Você consegue ver que ele só piora as coisas (pelo menos neste caso)? Você está confundindo tudo... Aposto que você não faz ideia do motivo de estar usando este padrão.

Comment: Por que é necessário?

Comment: Você tem como ler o meu comentário na pergunta e adicionar os detalhes que eu pedi?

Comment: @jbueno É verdade nao me parece que o AP tenha o código bem organizado

Comment: Entendi um pouco mais, caso fosse necessario no mensagemServico eu poderia fazer um getmany personalizado que adicionasse o Cliente.
Veja o meu comentario na principal sobre a estrutura , se não fosse seguir o DDD quais outras opções de projeto ? tem algum artigo para eu poder seguir ?

Comment: @WilliamCézar Eu nao quero estar a procura na internet. Mas posso-lhe dizer que vai encontrar **muitas mas mesmo muitas formas** diferentes de fazer. A maiora parte delas estao corretas ou fazem sentido, outras nem tanto. Voce tem que arranjar uma que funcione para si. Se voce precisar de ver exemplos tem que esperar que outra pessoa lhe diga, ou procure voce mesmo.

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer , agora faz mais sentido, esse getMany e um metodo que esta na BaseServico, no caso todos os meus serviços possuem ele, muito obrigado pela paciência vou em informar melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Já que estás usando EntityFrameWork, acredito que você precisa acrescentar a cláusula `Include`quando você pesquisa a entidade `Mensagem`.

Pelo jeito hoje você deve estar fazendo algo assim :

```
   var query = from msg in db.MensagemUnidade
            select msg;
```

Neste caso, por causa do conceito de [Lazy Loading](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20646/como-funciona-o-lazy-load-entity-framework), o entidade Cliente não será carregada.

Então mude a query para

```
 var query = from msg in db.MensagemUnidade.Include(c => c.Cliente)
            select msg;
```

Dessa forma a entidade Cliente é carregada.

Este artigo também explica o comportamento : https://ferhenriquef.com/2012/03/19/uso-de-include-em-consultas-com-o-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: `por causa do conceito de Lazy Loading, o entidade Cliente não será carregada`. Antes pelo contrário, por ter `Lazy Loading` a entidade `Cliente` **pode** ser carregada, **mas apenas se o código aceder a ela**