# DDD e Entity Framework são mutualmente exclusivos?

Tags: entity-framework, ddd

[Estava a trocar uns comentários com dois utilizadores aqui do `SOPT` sobre `DDD` e `Entity Framework`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163020/problema-com-heran%C3%A7a-c-asp-net?noredirect=1#comment335336_163020).

Eu afirmei que `DDD` e `Entity Framework` não são mutualmente exclusivos.

Ou será que são?

Referencias:

[O que é realmente o DDD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19548/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-ddd-e-quando-ele-se-aplica)

[Quando usar entity framework com repository pattern](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51536/quando-usar-entity-framework-com-repository-pattern/80696#80696)

Comment: Pode linkar esses comentários também?

Comment: @jbueno os comentários nao podem ser linkados (que eu saiba) mas vou incluir na pergunta.

Comment: Claro que podem. É só copiar o link em cima da hora do comentário.

Comment: @jbueno. Ah obrigado. Feito.

Comment: DDD não é tecnologia nem camadas.Foque no DDD http://eduardopires.net.br/2016/08/ddd-nao-e-arquitetura-em-camadas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma alguma!

O DDD  prega que entidades de domínio não devem estar cientes de como ocorre a persistência. Mas isso não quer dizer que ela não existe! No final do dia persistência ainda é necessária. Uma camada linda de domínio não faz muito por si só.

O que deve ser feito se você pratica DDD é garantir que a arquitetura do seu software é bem desenhada e acima de tudo *separada em camadas bem definidas.*

Entidades de domínio devem brincar em um canto e entidades de persistência em outro, ligadas (preferencialmente) através de data transfer objects(DTO's).

Em suma o DDD foca na área de domínio, mas não exclui a persistência(EF). São conceitos complementares na construção de um programa.

Comment: você acabou de descrever uma arquitetura multi-camadas, no caso 3 camadas, porém a maioria dos desenvolvedores cometem o erro de tentar ver a camada de persistência como sendo um projeto da sua solução, quando na verdade ela é simplesmente o SGBD. Então imagine uma aplicação SPA feito com AngularJS e WebAPI fazendo persistência no SQL Server, o AngularJS é a camada de apresentação, a WebAPI é a de dominio (sendo que o EF é componente dela) e o SQL Server é a camada de persistência.

Comment: @TobyMosque `SQL Server` nao é a camada de persistencia, ele é apenas uma base de dados. Onde os dados persistem. Uma camada de persistencia normalmente abstrai ligacoes á base de dados, query strings, parametros de queries e comandos, transformacao de um `record` para um modelo e mais mil e uma coisas. [Ou seja elas abstraeem o ADO.net (no caso do `c#`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TobyMosque No seu exemplo `EF` seria a camada de persisténcia e nada mais. Aliás ela é somente isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

O DDD é uma abordagem de modelagem de software que segue um conjunto de práticas com objetivo de facilitar a implementação de complexas regras / processos de negócios que tratamos como domínio.Esta abordagem não depende de nenhuma tecnologia para ser construído é também não é uma tecnologia.

O Repository pattern pode ser usado em conjunto com DDD na camada de infrastructure sem nenhum problema.